# How is Java sorting this ArrayList correctly with a logically-flawed Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

While working on an assignment, I found that for the following code Java sorts my ArrayList of points correctly (given the conditions in my comparator), with or WITHOUT the second if statement in the SlopeOrder compare method. How is it possible that Java can sort these points correctly when its told that two points are equal whenever a > b?

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point>
{
   ...

   public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() 
   {
       return new SlopeOrder();
   }

   private class SlopeOrder implements Comparator<Point> 
   {
      public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) 
      {
         double a = slopeTo(o1);
         double b = slopeTo(o2);
         if (a < b) return -1;
         if (a > b) return +1; // <--- Can be removed and list will still be sorted correctly
         return 0;
      }
   }

   ...

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

      points.add(new Point(1,1));
      points.add(new Point(4,6));
      points.add(new Point(6,6));
      points.add(new Point(3,9));
      points.add(new Point(0,0));
      points.add(new Point(5,2));

      Point origin = new Point(0,0);
      Collections.sort(points, origin.slopeOrder());
      System.out.println(points);
   }
}
```

Note: slopeTo just returns the slope of the given point (origin in this case) to some other point on the coordinate plane

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (5, 2), (1, 1), (6, 6), (4, 6), (3, 9)]
```

Comment: Could it be just a coincidence? Does it sort other points correctly too?

Comment: I can reproduce on my Java 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a coincidence.

I tried putting 100 random points in your list. The first dozen or more in the sorted list were sorted correctly, but then after (1, 9), (0, 3) started a new sorted sequence with (4, 0), (7, 1), etc. The entire sorted list contained just 4 subsequences each of which was correctly sorted.

It’s an amusing result.

Your flawed comparator returns 0 in some cases where it shouldn’t. 0 causes those elements to stay in the order they were. So it doesn’t in itself guarantee a wrong sorting order.

I used Oracle jdk-11.0.3.